# Search upto a delimiter using regular expression

Tags: regex, python-2.7

In the below string I need to use re.findall for '(any day)' then have it print upto the delimiter ',' prior

```
rr='PU3lserver1^server2|ABAP|Revisions|true|null|Weekend 
only,ATN|server3|ABAP|Revisions|true|null|1:00 AM to 3:00 AM CET (any 
day),B4P|server4^server5|ABAP|Revisions|true|Generic AFL|8:00 PM to 3:00 AM 
CET (any day),C8B|server6|ABAP|Revisions|true|Generic AFL|8:00 PM to 3:00 AM 
CET (any day),QU8|testserver|ABAP|Revisions|true|null|1:00 AM to 3:00 AM CET 
(any day),S77|testserver|ABAP|Revisions|true|null|Weekend only'
```

works well as expected:

```
re.findall(r'[^\s,]+Weekend\s\bonly' ,rr, re.M)
```

Does not work as expected:

```
re.findall(r'[\s,]+\(any\s\bday\)' ,rr, re.M)
```

Any help or suggestion where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You were almost correct

All you need to do is to change the character class to negation as

```
r'[^,]+\(any\s\bday\)'
```

- `[^,]+` Negated character class, matches anything other than `,` till `any day` is found
- `re.M` can be dropped as the input is single lined

**Test**

```
>>> re.findall(r'[^,]+\(any\s\bday\)' ,rr)
['B4P|server4^server5|ABAP|Revisions|true|Generic AFL|8:00 PM to 3:00 AM \nCET (any day)', 
 'C8B|server6|ABAP|Revisions|true|Generic AFL|8:00 PM to 3:00 AM \nCET (any day)', 
 'QU8|testserver|ABAP|Revisions|true|null|1:00 AM to 3:00 AM CET \n(any day)']
```

Comment: The `multi-line` mode modifier is not needed either.

Comment: @hwnd I agree with you. Copied from op's code. Corrected now in the answer. Thank you

Comment: Yes re.M is not needed, I had lot of other files where I am using this sting to get the data. 
Completely agree multi-line not needed here